JSLT expression using intermediate variables does not compile
I'm trying to compile a JSLT expression in Java with com.schibsted.spt.data. The expression needs intermediate variables and I got compilation errors.
This is what i tried:
String jsltExpression = "let parts = split(.id, \"/\") { \"result\": parts[1] + parts[3] }";
Expression jslt = Parser.compileString(jsltExpression);

error:
com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.JsltException: Parse error: Encountered " "[" "[ "" at line 1, column 46.
Was expecting:
    "(" ...
     at <inline>:1:41
    at com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.parser.ParserImpl.compileExpression(ParserImpl.java:62)
    at com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.Parser.compile(Parser.java:226)
    at com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.Parser.compileString(Parser.java:86)
    at com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.Parser.compileString(Parser.java:74)

Also tried:
String jsltExpression = "{ \"result\": let(parts = split(.id, \"/\")) parts[1] + parts[3] }";
Expression jslt = Parser.compileString(jsltExpression);

error:
com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.JsltException: Parse error: Encountered " "let" "let "" at line 1, column 13.
Was expecting one of:
    <INTEGER> ...
    <DECIMAL> ...
    <STRING> ...
    "[" ...
    "{" ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "." ...
    "if" ...
    "(" ...
    <IDENT> ...
    <PIDENT> ...
    <VARIABLE> ...
     at <inline>:1:11
    at com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.parser.ParserImpl.compileExpression(ParserImpl.java:62)
    at com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.Parser.compile(Parser.java:226)
    at com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.Parser.compileString(Parser.java:86)
    at com.schibsted.spt.data.jslt.Parser.compileString(Parser.java:74)

Is it possible to compile an expressien lika that with com.schibsted.spt.data? or is there any limitation?

You have to use $ to access the parts value, like this:
String jsltExpression = "let parts = split(.id, \"/\") { \"result\": $parts[1] + $parts[3] }";

You can try jslt expression in the playground (https://www.garshol.priv.no/jslt-demo), it gives you more feedback on errors and the chanche to craft specific input data for testing your expressions.
